# Why is this transaction slow when connected to a remote machine?

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, remote-access

I write about 500 records each minute to a SQL Server database on my local machine in NY. I have used the transaction approach. Here is code outline of what I do. `SqlInsertCommand` is NOT given as it quite complex.

When I run this in NY to a NY DB on my local machine it takes 40ms.

When all I do is change the connection string to an identical DB in LDN the process takes **35 seconds**!

Obviously, I was expecting it to take longer as crossing from NY to LDN is 80ms, but this is way more than I expected.

Am I using `Transaction` incorrectly? I thought that it collected all insert statements and sent them in one go on `Commit`.

Why might this be taking so long?

```
SqlConnection connForPA;
SqlTransaction transactionForPA;

public void Go()
{
     OpenConnectionAsTransactionForUpdate1M("BarEndProcess");

     try
     {
          foreach(var anItem in ListOfItems)
          {
               SqlInsertCommand(anItem);
          }
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
          transactionForPA.Rollback();
          return;
     }

     transactionForPA.Commit();
}

public static void OpenConnectionAsTransactionForPA(string transactionName)
{
    string connectionString = "user id=xxx;" +
                              @"password=xxxxx;" +
                               "server=xxxxxx;" +
                               "Trusted_Connection=no;" +
                               "database=TestDATA; " +
                               "MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" +
                               "connection timeout=30";

    if (connForPA != null)
    {
        if (connForPA.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            transactionForPA = connForPA.BeginTransaction(transactionName);
            return;
        }
    }

    connForPA = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    try
    {
        connForPA.Open();
        transactionForPA = connForPA.BeginTransaction(transactionName);
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        throw new Exception("[OpenConnectionAsTransactionForPA] Cannot open connection: " + err.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: hard to entirely say as "long" is relative, but, consider this, between your machine and your sql there is an almost infinite speed network.. between your pc and someone elses .. there isnt.

Comment: can you check wait stats,using below query,when the query runs on `identical DB in LDN`

Comment: `select * from sys.dm_Exec_requests ec cross apply sys.dm_Exec_sql_text(ec.sql_handle) b`

Comment: you can identify your query from above query and try to see what  are the wait stats

Comment: Perhaps it's performing an auto DTC enrollment?

Comment: where is your insert command?

Comment: @TheGameiswar Shouldn't data only be arriving in LDN on Commit? I thought the transaction was entirely batched.

Comment: what does it meant by on commit.sql transfers the data in packets.The default packet size is 4,096 bytes

Comment: "I thought that it collected all insert statements and sent them in one go on Commit." No. Every individual statement is sent and processed as it is issued, but the server doesn't need to finalize writing the data (and acknowledge that it has done so) until the commit. Gathering together statements in a transaction will still speed up things (as the number of necessary transaction log waits is reduced), but the statements aren't "collected" in the sense you're talking about.

Comment: If network transfer speeds/roundtrip times *are* an issue, consider using a table-valued parameter or `SqlBulkCopy` to send over the raw data, then processing all rows at once with one `INSERT` statement on the server. Alternatively, you can concatenate all `INSERT` commands textually, but the T-SQL parser has bad scaling behavior and your batch can easily get "too large". You also run into issues with escaping, or are forced to declare a very long parameter list, so I'd look into other options first.

Comment: All that said, if you are issuing the `INSERT` statements with `ExecuteNonQuery` and `SET NOCOUNT ON`, the network latency *should* not matter since the statements should just be sent over without only the delay of a single packet. But if there is a roundtrip between the statements that's waited on, that might explain the delay you're seeing.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I changed my code to write to local DB, then drag in table from local DB to a c# DataTable. Then I use SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DT). Wow - that is lightning fast from NY to LDN! Why is there no SqlBulkCOpy.WriteToserver(<From another DB table>) option. Creating a DataTable in the middle seems unnecessary.

Comment: `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer` has an overload that takes an `IDataReader`. You can directly stream between tables this way (speed may suffer slightly in the synchronization, but memory overhead is reduced). If your data is not in a table to begin with, you can cobble together your own `IDataReader` that serves the data directly from memory. This is a little more involved, but the technique should be detailed in other SO questions (too lazy to search now).

Comment: Do note that while `SqlBulkCopy` is the fastest way to pump data into a SQL Server table, it's not without issues -- specifically, the table is locked while the bulk insert happens, you need special permissions to bulk insert, and last but not least only "straight" copying is possible (no joins, filtering, etcetera). For only 500 rows, it may be slight overkill and a TVP may offer comparable performance with less hassle.